# Carousel item position changes everyday!! (Django , materialize)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

My Carousel/Carousel-Item dimensions are not fitting in nicely on the page. I left it at 1800px yesterday and there was no gap between navbar and carousel item. now there is. ([gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqAZN.png))

Not sure where i'm going wrong. When i reduce the carousel size to 900 px it cuts off lines from the carousel item as described below.

[carousel item over extending past carousel's height, hence misses lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WHzh.png)

Here's the html code in my django template.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
{% load index %}

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="container nav-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-container">

        <h class="brand-logo center"><b>Today's Q/A</b></h>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="Center">
            <li><a href="/"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    });

autoplay()
function autoplay() {
    $('.carousel').carousel('next');
    setTimeout(autoplay, 4500);
}
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
{#<section class="black">#}

<style>
html,
body{
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}
 .flex-container {
  display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;

}
</style>

<div class="flex-container">

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light" href="/random_naturemetal_link">Cute Cat Pic <3
    <i class="large material-icons left">sentiment_neutral</i>
    <i class="large material-icons right">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light" href="/random_cozy_link"> C O Z Y
    <i class="large material-icons left">favorite</i>
    <i class="large material-icons right">favorite</i>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light" href="/random_sky_link"> Trippy Earth
    <i class="large material-icons left">camera</i>
    <i class="large material-icons right">flight_takeoff</i>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>

{#</section>#}
<style>
.carousel
{
  height: auto !important;
}

.carousel-item
{
  display: flex;
    {#margin-top: -5%;#}
    width: 1050 !important;
    height: auto! important;
  align-items: space-evenly! important;
  justify-content: space-evenly! important;
}

</style>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container carousel">

{%for a, b in x|zip:z %}

    <div class="carousel-item black lighten-2 white-text" href="#">
      <div class="container">
      <br>

        <h3 class="align-center">{{a}}</h3>
       {% for i in b %}
          <p>{{ i }}</p>
           {%  endfor %}
            <div class ="container">
                <a href={{random_meme}}>
                <h3 class="">dank meme 4 u</h3>
                <br>
            </a>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}


</div>


{#    <div class="carousel-item red lighten-2 white-text" href={{random_meme}}>#}
{#            <div class ="container">#}
{#                <a href={{random_meme}}>#}
{#            <h2> dank meme 4 u</h2>#}
{#            </a>#}
{#            </div>#}
{##}
{#            <h1> Thanks for staying <br>#}
{#            <a href = {{random_meme}} target="_blank"> dank meme 4 u <3 </h1></a>#}
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>

</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
   var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, {
     indicators: true,
     padding: 200,
   });
 });
</script>


{#    </form>#}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS Couldn't replicate the for loop for carousel items while transitioning from DTL. Really feel its something in the css carousel settings. Will try to host the site on heroku and then maybe having a working example to link here.

Comment: hi @jqueryHtmlCSS as promised, pfb link for website ezqna.herokuapp.com